# Don't Save macro

Tags: vba, excel

I need to open and close a file using a macro, but I don't want to save it. I can get to wear excel prompts you to Save or Don't save, what is the VBA command for dont save. This is what I am using I just need it to not save and close excel all the way.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Sheet6").Select
Range("A1").Select

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "X:\File.xlsx"
Workbooks.Close
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place `False` in first argument after Close method to tell VBA to not save the Workbook changes. So:

```
Workbooks.Close False
```

or

```
Workbooks.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, try to use `Application.DisplayAlerts`:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts=False
Workbooks.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts=True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Saved` property of the `Workbook` object for this. Setting this property to `True` will stop the prompt from appearing (but won't actually save the workbook):

```
Dim wb as workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("X:\File.xlsx")

' do stuff here

wb.Saved = True
wb.Close
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196613.aspx for reference